# What is CorLoc which is used to evaluate object detection performance?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

I tried to understand this evaluatation method for object detection.

My understanding is, the neural networks will give a bounding box for a target object and CorLoc evaluates only positive images which contain the target class, and counts the percentage of images for IOU > 0.5:

CorLoc = (the boxes that IOU > 0.5) / (all boxes belong to the target class)

e.g. there are 100 bounding boxes for car, but just 60 bounding box's IOU > 0.5, so the corloc is 60/100 = 60%

I found this image where there are three bounding boxes:

red bbox means IOU < 0.5
green box means IOU > 0.5

CorLoc is therefore 2/3 = 66%

But I don't understand why ignore the rightmost motorbike
and why just evaluate CorLoc on traing dataset or something I need to know about corloc?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Corloc is to compute the number of the right boxes you have been detected. The formulation is TP/TP+FP. The rightmost bounding box is neither TP or FP but FN. Thus there are only 3 detections(TP+FP) with 2 positive(TP). Corloc=2/3=66%

Answer (score 0):

I guess Corloc is only about how many of the boxes your network has detected are actually right. So since there is no detection for the rightmost car (the yellow box is the gt) there are only 3 detections in total, two of which are correct(iou > 0.5) and one is wrong.